Multiple rows for one variable on a row by row basis
I am implementing a stored procedure and I want to store multiple rows in a variable. This should kind of be in a row by row basis. I read some information online about making a cursor and doing a loop or something like that. I am kind of struggling with my scenario.
In the code, the case can have 2-5 income sources for an individual. I need to store those income sources in a variable to reuse later to store into another table. I know some may say what I'm doing maybe redundant but I left out a lot of code to simplify and understand the process.
PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA(
    P_IND_ID IN T_IND
    -- Parameter being passed later to get
) 
IS
    -- Variables to use later. Income source variable will be used to store multiple rows.
    V_INCOME_SRC T_INCOME_SRC.SRC_INCOME%TYPE
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SRC_INCOME
    INTO
        V_INCOME_SRC
    FROM
        T_INCOME_SRC I
    WHERE
        I.IND_ID = P_IND_ID;

    INSERT INTO SECOND_TABLE (INCOMES)
        SELECT
            V_INCOME_SRC

I tried doing LISTAGG but I'm not sure if that was incorrect in this scenario.
I think BULK COLLECT and FORALL INSERT might work in this scenario but a bit confused on how to implement

Is there a reason why you can't use an insert-select statement to get the values and insert them in the same statement?

That is what I initially did but one variable should be able to stored more than one row of data and output each data row by row.

I don't have your table(s) so this example is based on Scott's sample schema and shows two options you might use. I'll fetch employees that belong to certain department and insert them into another table.
These names should be inserted:
SQL> select ename from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER

This is the target table:
SQL> create table emp_new (type varchar2(10), ename varchar2(10));

Table created.

Procedure: it uses Oracle's built-in datatype (sys.odcivarchar2list) as - in your example - you're selecting only one column. If you want (or if in real scenario you use more than a single column), create your own type and use it.
SQL> create or replace procedure insert_data
  2    (p_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  3  is
  4    v_enames sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    delete from emp_new;
  7
  8    select ename
  9      bulk collect into v_enames
 10      from emp
 11      where deptno = p_deptno;
 12
 13    -- 1st option
 14    forall i in 1 .. v_enames.count
 15      insert into emp_new (type, ename) values ('A', v_enames(i));
 16
 17    -- 2nd option
 18    insert into emp_new (type, ename)
 19      select 'B', column_value
 20        from table (v_enames);
 21  end;
 22  /

Procedure created.

Let's try it:
SQL> exec insert_data(10);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from emp_new;

TYPE       ENAME
---------- ----------
A          CLARK
A          KING
A          MILLER
B          CLARK
B          KING
B          MILLER

6 rows selected.

SQL>

[EDIT] If you have more than a single column, as I said - create your own type. In the following example I'm selecting both name and job.
Target table and procedure:
SQL> create table emp_new (type varchar2(10), ename varchar2(10), job varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure insert_data
  2    (p_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  3  is
  4    type     v_enames_r is record (ename varchar2(10), job varchar2(10));
  5    type     v_enames_t is table of v_enames_r index by pls_integer;
  6    v_enames v_enames_t;
  7  begin
  8    delete from emp_new;
  9
 10    select ename, job
 11      bulk collect into v_enames
 12      from emp
 13      where deptno = p_deptno;
 14
 15    forall i in 1 .. v_enames.count
 16      insert into emp_new (type, ename, job)
 17        values ('A', v_enames(i).ename, v_enames(i).job);
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.

Testing:
SQL> exec insert_data(10);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from emp_new;

TYPE       ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ----------
A          CLARK      MANAGER
A          KING       PRESIDENT
A          MILLER     CLERK

SQL>


Thank you for your response. What if if have more variables in this query but only want to bulk collect into one of the variables? I need the other variables for joins. For example:
select ename, id,dept
into var 2 , var3
bulk collect into v_enames
from emp, t_id, t_dept
where deptno = p_deptno
t_id.id = t_dept.id
;

You're welcome. Have a look at edited answer, please.
